# XSLT 2.0 PHP support. When?

Tags: php, xslt, saxon

What are the chances to see XSLT 2.0 processors like saxon for php in the nearest future?

Comment: You can always shell out XSLT processing to an external XSLT 2.0 capable processor if need be…

Comment: In my opinion "Never with the [performance](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/xslt-benchmarks.html) of [XSLT 1.0 processors](http://www.xmlsoft.org/XSLT.html)"... For middleware and data interchange, like in Gnome project, user needs performance, and need to perform single tasks (like old DTD validation and simple XSLT filters). For database applications (ex. consider the lack of xQuery at PostgreSQL) the PHP and [public software communities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software_community) need to evolve and must justify open-source investments, agains existing options showed here.

Comment: **Good news** Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20275114/36305

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the nearest future? None.

PHP5 relies exclusively on [LibXSLT](http://xmlsoft.org/xslt/) for XSLT processing (Sablotron is out), and there is no plan to support XSLT 2.0 in this library.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't entirely true.

If you are running PHP on the Windows platform, then there is a relatively easy to configure extension to the AltovaXML XSLT 2.0 processor... http://sourceforge.net/projects/xslt2processor/

If you are running PHP on Linux, then you will need to install a PHP/Java Bridge. This involves running a Java servlet contained like Apache/Tomcat, and is pretty involved. There is also some relatively complex hybrid java/php code necessary to make this work. If you are interested, I can post more details.

Comment: @JR: For the future - please use comments for this kind of answer (I know you can't comment *yet*). Answers like this one get out of context as soon as up/down votes are cast and the list of answers gets re-sorted.

Answer (score 3):

**Finally, there is a positive answer to this question**.

Just today, Dr. Michael Kay announced **[Saxon/C](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml)**.

See this for more information: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/20275114/36305**

Comment: Awesome thank you!! But I wish this was announced more than 2 weeks ago as I was scraping the web for something like this. either way time to refactor and upgrade to xstl 2.0 :)

Comment: @RezaSanaie, Yes, XSLT 1.0 is 14 years old  -- ancient in internet time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `XSLT2.o` support till now in PHP, the only option to use XSLT2.0 is to use SAXON which is java based and hence you will have to something like PHP XSLT2.0 processor, see this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xslt2processor/

> `XML_XSLT2Processor` is a PHP class that allows you to perform XSLT
>   2.0 transformations within PHP by using SAXON or AltovaXML.

Comment: saxon/c is not java based, its written in c++ ... http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml and here is php api for saxon/c http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/index.html#php-api

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source XSL 2.0 transpiler in PHP that can be found on [github](https://github.com/genkgo/xsl)

Also Saxon/C version 1.0.0 supporting XSLT 2.0/3.0 on C/C++ and PHP [has been released](http://www.saxonica.com/html/saxon-c/release-notes.html).

Answer (score 0):

PHP use LibXML2 to implement all XML classes. It is very fast and stable, but today (2013) only supports XPath1 and XSLT1... **Perhaps** community need only this faster and simpler solution, and *not need the powers of XSLT2* (see  "option0").

### option0: try to use better MVC separation!

... Many templates, used as *View* in a MVC context, *not need the powers of XSLT2*: see  [good explanation why](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Eparrt/papers/mvc.templates.pdf). See how some good PHP projects are using XSLT1

### option1: try a non-mainstream implementation

As [showed by @collapsar at this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7530767/287948) there
are a open source developed to extend the classic [LibXML2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) with some powers of XSLT2 and XPath2.
See
http://www.explain.com.au/libx/

PHP community not yet motivated to complete this evolution... Why? Maybe just afraid of losing some performance and stability. [Maybe just a lack of manpower to complete the task](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/205581/84349), mainly in a PHP driver.

### option2: empower XSLT1 or XPath1 with PHP functions/conections

See example of [usual workawound here, by registering PHP functions into XPath1 or XSLT1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20203444/287948). I am using this solution at my projects.