# xsl:value-of is adding white space

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have XSLT like:

```
<xsl:variable name="letter">
  <xsl:value-of select="@display_value"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

and somewhere I use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$letter"/>
```

But this is adding extra space.  I'd like to use `xsl:text`, but it doesn't take a variable.

Do you have suggestions, please, on how to get rid of the space?

Comment: Show the input and output XML that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I think Normalize-space() would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be better if you showed us sample input XML and output XML.  Without that, one might guess that `@display_value` in the input XML has more white space than you'd like.  You could use [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) when you define `letter`:

```
<xsl:variable name="letter">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@display_value)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

or when you use it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($letter)"/>
```

Note, however, that `normalize-space()` is not the same as `trim` in other languages in that it will reduce repetitive whitespace internal to a string, not just on its ends.

See also "[How to Trim in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4409482/290085)".

---

**Update per new comment from OP:**

Another possibility (apparently **the** reason in this case) is that the context into which `$letter` is output has significant white space that one is mistakenly attributing to `$letter` itself.  Changing this:

```
[
<xsl:value-of select="$letter"/>
]
```

to this:

```
<xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$letter"/>
<xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
```

helped resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, apparently the issue wasn't the on the variable. I have braces [ and ] surrounding  <xsl:value-of select="$letter"/>. I put the braces inside xsl:text, like <xsl:text>[</xsl:text> and <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>. This fixed it

Comment: Ah, ok.  I've edited the answer to reflect this possibility for posterity's sake.  Thanks for the follow-up.